# Morlet wavelet transform of binary dataset in R

Tags: data-analysis, wavelets

I want to perform a Morlet Wavelet transform analysis (WTA) on a sequence of binary data (0, 1), length about 19000 observations. The result seems reasonable, but I have my doubts whether WTA can be performed on a binary dataset, not technically, but mathematically.

I used the most simple code in R with the `WaveletComp` package after filtering out the high frequency signal with the `astrochron` package

`res=bandpass(dat, flow=1/100000000, fhigh=1/10, win=0)`

`res_every10=analyze.wavelet(my.data= res, my.series =2, loess.span = 0, dt = 1, dj = 1/12, method="AR", params = list(AR=list(p=1)))`

I also attached a sample dataset [`here`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SxdH5QJE6pJqP3KcavtvFkjJAQA8OWK3/edit?rtpof=true&sd=true#gid=1021614223). Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: you could ask the same question about the Fourier transformation of binary data; this is a perfectly valid operation, why would it be any different for the Morlet transform?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker thank you for input. I wondered this because I have not found any example on such an application, only to binary images and I thought there may be some underlying prerequisite that I am not aware of....

Comment: @CarloBeenakker if you could provide a reference in which it has been done on data series instead of image processing I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfectly valid operation.

Here is one reference where a Morlet wavelet analysis has been applied to a binary data set: [Morlet wavelet transforms of heart rate variability for autonomic nervous system activity](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280319349_Monet_wavelet_transforms_of_heart_rate_variability_for_autonomic_nervous_system_activity), see section 2.1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!